# React - remounting components on url change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

So I am working on React/redux app with react-router v4.
Page structure is more or less this:

```
<html>
    <head>...</head>
    <body>
        <aside>
            <NavigationComponent />
        </aside>
        <main>
            <ItemComponent />
        </main>
    </body>
</html>
```

So I pretty much render an `<ItemComponent />` within `main` depending on the url the user is on, say either `/11` or `/231`. The way I do this currently is use redux's `mapStateToProps` to retrieve `item` out of `items` by `id`, using react-router injected props, namely `params`. Then `item` is passed to  as a prop and so the contents get rendered. However, prop changes, namely `item` changes, only trigger difference rerenders.
How would I accomplish unmounting current `<ItemComponent />` and mounting a new one? Or better yet, what's the best way to animate this component, say when entering and leaving (triggered by url change)?

I managed to hack something around using ReactTransitionGroup addon, however I am interested in the cleanest way to accomplish this.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why do you need to `ItemComponent` to unmount? Why not just listen for changes using `componentWillReceiveProps` or `componentDidUpdate`?

Comment: Fair enough, I mean that's what I am doing now, more or less. However, how would you handle animation? Say animating one item out, while animating another in?